# Javascript - Changing contents of a slideshow's div on timer, results in all elements being overlaid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slideshow, but would like to periodically change the contents of the slideshow.

Based on fairly standard jQuery/CSS3 from many many websites, running on localhost, I have...

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
            var changeSlide = setInterval(function() {
              $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(500)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(500)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
            }, 2000);

            var reLoadMyData = setInterval(function() {
                $("#slideshow").load("data.xml");
            },5000);
        });
    </script>
```

After reloading, all the (new) divs are overlaid on top of each other. However every 2 seconds one does disappear - it's just they get into a bad state.

- How can I fix the overlaid problem? I've tried `$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();` before/after loading data.xml, and tried removing all child elements of #slideshow, however this has no effect.
- Is there a way I can load() at the 'end' of the divs, without requiring a second Interval (which is a bit messy really)?

Comment: You could keep an index of the current slide and then reload when it matches the number of slides. Also, I can't remember but load may just append more divs instead of replacing them - so you may also want to clear out the old HTML each time you load.

Comment: @lemieuxster - I guessed that too, but it seems like load() *is* replacing the original contents of the div (I have tried different values in index.htm and data.xml!). I will look into the index idea - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, for the overlaid issue, the problem is that you're not hiding the new divs once more after the load is complete. To achieve this, you need to add the hiding action inside the load() function.

```
$("#slideshow").load("data.xml", function(){
     // On load complete, do stuff
     $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
});
```

Also, you may want to use the following as reference https://api.jquery.com/load/ and add the parameters as responseText, textStatus, to verify that your load was succesful and hide the divs only if the call succeeded and display a message if it failed to

And my apologies for misunderstanding the issue in my previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .load doesn't allow appending data to an element. Instead consider using $.get

```
$('#slideshow').get("data.xml", function(data){
    // when load is complete append to element
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to _replace_ the divs, not append to them. The problem is that after the replacement, all the (new) divs are overlaid (it may be useful to try it).

Comment: I understood your sentence wrong "at the 'end' of the divs", I believe you meant to insert at the end of the first interval or animation? For the overlaid issue, it might be probably because you're not hiding the divs after loading them via the .load. You're calling the hide action only on doc ready '$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();'

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I've tried adding that line below load(), but it makes no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: it shouldn't be below, but inside, .load('data.xml', function(){ // on load complete, hide the divs once more })

Comment: Amazing - that works perfectly. If you want to post that as a separate answer, I'd be delighted to accept that answer. Thank you for your patience!